# CSS Grid align-items: baseline not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-grid, text-align

I've come across a problem where the "align-item: baseline;" is not working in Safari. It works in Chrome and Firefox. Is this a bug or is there something I am missing?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/yxdqZK?editors=1100#

HTML

```
<section class="grid">
  <ul class="item_1">
    <li>detail 1</li>
    <li>detail 2</li>
    <li>detail 3</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="item_2">Ovid unturib uscium quidel ium Illatquibusam aut elessin velest, ium sim ea nulliqui deribus andam, coriam enem eatiur?</p>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:15ch 40ch;
  align-items:baseline;
}

.item_1 {
  grid-column:1;
  font-size:1rem;
  line-height:1;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.item_2 {
  grid-column:2;
  font-size:1.25rem;
  line-height:1.2;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if other values for `align-items` work in Safari?

Comment: Positional alignments (start, center, end) seem to be working but none of the baseline alignments. I'm on the latest Safari update.

Comment: There is a known issue with webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199648. While maybe not exactly the issue, it could be related.

Answer (score 1):

I've run across similar issues, also with the current version of Safari (12.0.3), where `align-items: end;` and/or `align-items: center;` aren't working.

In testing this, though, I did find that `align-content: end;` worked for me in Safari, and didn't seem to create issues in Firefox. You may want to try it, but check if it breaks you layouts, especially for responsive breakpoints.